# Sync Dropbox to External hard drive, unlinking, etc

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sync, dropbox

My laptop is jam packed full in terms of storage (it is quite old and has limited storage anyway) and I have just got some external hard drives to free up some space.

Approx. 30GB of this is partially synced Dropbox files. I have approx. 200GB on Dropbox itself. I have already backed up the DB folders on my computer to the external hard drive, and what I wanted to do was to change the link for the dropbox sync to the external hard drive and delete the files on C drive.

My plan was to unlink dropbox and then re-set up with folders in new location for syncing & then delete files on computer when complete (weeks?!).

a) Is it a good idea to sync to an external hard drive from DB?

b) Is there a more efficient way to achieve what I would like to do?

c) Is it necessary to name the hard drive first to avoid misreading and misappointing directory names when changing external hard drives?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm looking for something similar, so I'll just share here my findings.

[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io) - You can use Cyberduck to sync your dropbox with an external HDD. I found the sync feature not super reliable and it doesn't delete removed files, it always add the files back.

[pCloud](https://www.pcloud.com) - pCloud replaces DB completely and it also syncs with external HDD, but again their sync function with external drives are not reliable another option would be Sync.com

odrive - probably the best way, but expensive!

I'm still looking for a better solution to those.