# Using a cloud service simultaneously with both an internal and external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, dropbox

Here's my scenario: I have an internal drive on my laptop (which I take with me) and an external drive that stays in one place.

I use Dropbox for cloud storage. The external hard drive holds huge files that I need (photos/videos) but don't access on a daily basis. The internal drive holds all documents and day-to-day files.

The question is this: is there a way to have two separate folders in Dropbox (or any other cloud storage provider) that can have my daily files that I sync to my internal HDD and then the larger files that I sync to my external HDD without having two accounts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something similar and posted a couple of my findings [here](https://superuser.com/a/1185525/704265).

Cyberduck - You can use Cyberduck to sync your dropbox with an external HDD. I found the sync feature not super reliable and it doesn't delete removed files, it always add the files back.

pCloud - pCloud replaces DB completely and it also syncs with external HDD, but again their sync function with external drives are not reliable another option would be Sync.com

odrive - probably the best way, but expensive!

I'm still looking for a better solution to those.

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of the link (even if it is here on SU) in your answer, if it fits.